# How to change the color of a menu item

Tags: menus, css

I want to change color to red for one menu page "Logowanie".
[image]

Anyone help how I can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to right click to the element you want to change color, then you will Inspect Element to know its ID, once you know the ID you have to [add custom CSS](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/) changing the color of that item like this:

```
#menu-item-391 a {
  color: red;
}
```

You can use [hex code](https://www.color-hex.com/) for the color if you don't want pure red.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Castiblanco will work, but using ID's for styling is a terrible idea. Add a class to your menu item and then adjust the color through your class.

```
.nav-link__red-class {    
  color: red;
}
```